# How can I describe the hermitian part of a tensor product of C*-algebras?

Tags: operator-theory, tensor-products, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I was trying to study the hermitian part of a C*-algebra defined as the tensor product of two C*-algebras.

Let $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ be C*-algebras. Consider $\mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{B}$ and the completion $\mathcal{A} \otimes_{\max} \mathcal{B}$ with the projective C*-cross-norm. Is it possible to describe the hermitian elements of $\mathcal{A} \otimes_{\max} \mathcal{B}$ as the tensor product of the hermitian elements of $\mathcal{A}$ and the ones in $\mathcal{B}$? Any references or bibliography about this topic?

Thank you.

Comment: Think finite-dimensional first, i.e. let $A,B$ be finite-dimensional $C^*$-algebras. Then there is no topology involved. Clearly there is an inclusion $A_{sa} \odot_{\mathbb{R}} B_{sa}\subseteq (A \odot_{\mathbb{R}} B)_{sa}$. What can you say about the converse inclusion?

Comment: In the finite-dimensional case, I think it is clear that you have the other inclusion, $(A \odot_\mathbb{R} B)_{sa} \subseteq A_{sa} \odot_\mathbb{R} B_{sa} $, as you can see the hermitian part of $A$ as $A\otimes \{ 1 \}$, and also for B. But I don't know if that could be extented to the infinite-dimensional case. Am I right? Thanks for your response.